# Display after class based on amount of items in loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am displaying data in html using in loop, inside it I got a class

```
div(v-for="item in items" :key="item.id")
 .circle
   p {{ item.name }}
```

in my css I got

```css
.circle::after
  content: ''
  background: grey
  height: 5px
  width: 130px
  position: absolute
  left: 0
  top: 16px
  z-index: -1
```

Can I display this after class only if there is more than 1 item in my loop?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Comment: @MichalLevý this doesn't seem to work with pseudo elements

Comment: I'm not familiar with pug, could I provide a solution using HTML?

Comment: @Boosa Of course it doesn't. `::after` pseudo element is CSS construct so you cannot control it using Vue. So the only option (IMHO) is to define two classes - one with `::after` and one without it and conditionally apply only one of the classes...

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, `::after` pseudo element is CSS construct so you cannot control it using Vue.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Define two classes - one with `::after` and one without it and [conditionally apply](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) only one of the classes based on the number of items
2. You can actually do it entirely with CSS using `:not(:only-child)` pseude-selector. See example below

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    toggle: true,
    items: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", id: 1 },
      { text: "Learn Vue", id: 2 },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", id: 3 },
      { text: "Build something awesome", id: 4 }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    computedItems() {
      return this.toggle ? this.items : this.items.slice(0,1)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.circle:not(:only-child)::after {
  content: " ➥";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle = !toggle">
    Switch items
  </button>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in computedItems" :key="item.id" class="circle">
      {{ item.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```